# NSArray stringByAppendingString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I need to append String by adding an array of Suit to an array of Rank, something like this.

```
-(NSString *)contents {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %@", self.rank, self.suit];
}
```

The correct code is written as below. I don't understand the code.
Does NSString return just 1 String or an array of String? 
What does the code [PlayingCard validRanks] do? 
Why does rankStr have to use [self.rank]? Why can't it use validRanks and validSuit directly?

```
-(NSString *)contents {

    NSArray *rankStr = [PlayingCard validRanks];

    return [rankStr [self.rank] stringByAppendingString: self.suit];
}
```

the rest of the code is:

```
#import "PlayingCard.h"

@implementation PlayingCard



-(NSString *)contents {

    NSArray *rankStr = [PlayingCard validRanks];

    return [rankStr [self.rank] stringByAppendingString: self.suit];
}   



@synthesize suit = _suit;

-(void)setSuit: (NSString *)suits {
    if ([[PlayingCard validSuits] containsObject:suits]) {
        _suit = suits;
    }
}

-(NSString *) suit {
     return _suit ? _suit : @"?";
}



@synthesize rank = _rank;


-(void)setRank: (NSUInteger)ranks {
    if (ranks <= [PlayingCard maxRank]) {
         _rank = ranks; }
}


+(NSUInteger) maxRank {
    return [self validRanks].count - 1;
} 


+(NSArray *) validSuits {
    return @[@"♥", @"♦", @"♠", @"♣"];
}


+(NSArray *) validRanks {
    return @[@"?", @"A", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", @"10", @"J", @"Q", @"K"];
}


@end
```

Thank you.

Comment: It's not as correct as you think it is. That code should be producing syntax errors.

Comment: Do your homework -- `[PlayingCard validRanks]` calls the method "validRanks".  If capitalization rules have been observed, "PlayingCard" is a class and "validRanks" is a class method.  If not, "PlayingCard" may be an instance pointer and "validRanks" an instance method.

Comment: it doesn't give an error. the code i put on top is just showing the part that I don't understand ...

Comment: If you come from C/Java it will take weeks, at least, to overcome the impulse to always view `[]` as an array index operation vs a method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had just written `[rankStr stringByAppendingString: self.suit]`, what would that mean? Well, `rankStr` is an NSArray. So we would have called `stringByAppendingString:` on the array of all ranks. Not only is that invalid since NSArray doesn't have any such method, but it wouldn't be what we wanted even if it did exist — we want to get the string representing *this card's rank* followed by the card's suit. So we index the array by the card's rank  — `rankStr[self.rank]` — which returns the element from the array corresponding to the `rank` of `self`.